# Sequential labelling with default value in attribute forms in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression, attribute-form

I'm building an attribute form in QGIS (3.24.1) for adding new features to a layer.

I have a field `"Quick ref ID"` which I want to have a default value. The default value needs to be in the format

> XYZ-[sample type]-#######

where XYZ is always XYZ, [sample type] refers to the value in another field `"Sample type"`, and ####### is a sequential number for that sample type - e.g. if the latest entry for a sample of type Alpha was XYZ-Alpha-0000099, the default value for the next one should be XYZ-Alpha-0000100.

It's also likely that new sample types will be added in future, so it has to check if Quick ref IDs exist for a sample type and, if not, to start from 0000001 for that type.

So far I've got to here (edited to update): `'XYZ-'||replace(upper("Sample type"),' ','_')||'-'||lpad(if(regexp_match("Quick ref ID",'XYZ-'||"Sample type"||'-') IS 0, 1, [else value]),7,'0')`

My most successful attempt of completing the part labelled `[else value]` has only succeeded in getting the default value to use the next number after the highest of *all* numbers, e.g. if the latest entry for a sample of type Alpha was XYZ-Alpha-0000099 and for a sample of type Beta was XYZ-Beta-0006424, the default value I got for the next Alpha was XYZ-Alpha-0006425.

I have several similar expressions that need implementing across a couple of projects and I've been at a dead end on this for a while, so it would be a lifesaver if anyone has an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
'XYZ-' ||  "Sample type" || '-'|| lpad( coalesce( to_int(aggregate(layer:='your_layer_name',aggregate:='max',expression:=( right("Quick ref ID",7)),
filter:="Sample type" = attribute(@parent,'Sample type')))+1,1),7,'0')
```

You need to replace `your_layer_name` with the actual name of your layer.

It uses the QGIS aggregate function on the layer to find 'max' of the 7 rightmost characters of the "Quick ref ID" where the "Sample Type" matches the current "Sample Type".  It then converts the max to an integer, increments it by 1 and pads it out with zeroes.  The `coalesce` is there to catch when a new "Sample type" is entered - the max comes back as NULL - the NULL is replaced with a 1.

Comment: That seems to have hit the nail on the head! I'd been playing round with the aggregate function this morning but couldn't wrap my head around it well enough to land on a solution. Thanks for such a complete and well-explained answer - you're an absolute hero!

I've got a few other similar implementations I need to do, which also gives me the chance to practice putting a couple of these together myself.

Huge thanks!